# HTML5 Geolocation problems on the IPhone 

Tags: iphone, html, geolocation

I am working on geolocation api html5, iphone results are disappointing. Tested on city ​​with tall buildings and watchPosition implementation

The main problems are:

Minimum accuracyfound: 49 meters

Normal accuracy: 75m

Returns many repeated positions. Big problem, the same 20 positions in one interval!

Options do not work: enable High Accuracy and maximunAge.
Speed variable not work

Running on Firefox Home for iphone, so when the phone is locked, d'ont stops web and GPS. 
Safari stop web when phone is locked.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect bad Safari implementation of this particular HTML5 feature.  I'm experiencing the same thing as you.  I'm specifying enableHighAccuracy: true, and the best accuracy I get is > 1400 meters.  Doesn't Apple believe me when I say I want high accuracy?   Native apps are very accurate under the same conditions.

Comment: Did you resolve this? If so, did it require a Safari or something upgrade? I'm also specifying `{enableHighAccuracy:true}` and the accuracy I see is 1414. (Though actually it "just" 500m wrong!) Private browsing on/off makes no difference, neither does clearing the cache/history. (iOS 6.1.3, Safari version 6.0)

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the `enableHighAccuracy` flag to your `getCurrentPosition` call? If not, the iPhone *may* be using cell triangulation to pinpoint your location (it's hard to know what Apple's internal implementation does, but it seems unlikely to be using the GPS given your results).

Have a read of [The specification for `getCurrentPosition`](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#get-current-position) - the high accuracy flag as part of the `PositionOptions` optional third parameter.